# mysql select / create unique id based on row name

Tags: mysql, select

This is my database table. How would i be able to select the bottom table from the database table?

Is it possible to create NameID and TypeID from unique names and types?

EDIT---
Ive got the type to work using case, since there are only 3 types.

```
SELECT 
  name, type, spending, 
    CASE type 
       WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'Cash' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'Cheque' THEN 3 
    END AS typeID_  
FROM spendtable
```

Would it be possible to do the same on the name column?

Thanks!

----database table----

> Name   Type         
>         Spending
>  John       Credit Card   550
>  Brian     Cash  
>             200
>  Frank    Cheque  
>         600
>  John      Cash        
>       150
>  John 
>        Cash             300
>   Frank    Credit
>   Card   200

----table needed ----

> NameID   Name   TypeID   Type   
>               Spending
>  1
>                 John      1            Credit Card
>        550
>  2
>                Brian     2
>              Cash                 200
>  3              Frank     3            Cheque   
>           600
>  1              John      2            Cash 
>                 150
>   1              John      2            Cash  
>                 300
>   3              Frank     1            Credit Card     200

-------EDIT

I ended up using 2 queries and php to get the required table

```
 function getInfo(){   
     SELECT 
       name, type, spending, 
         CASE type 
            WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'Cash' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'Cheque' THEN 3 
         END AS typeID_  
     FROM spendtable 
 }

 function getName(){   
       SELECT name    
       FROM spendtable   
       GROUP BY share_ ASC           
 }


$info_array = $this->getInfo(); 
$name_array = $this->getName(); 

 for($i=0; $i<count($info_array); $i++){   
   $info_array[$i]['nameID'] = '';   
     for($j=0; $j<count($name_array); $j++){
     if($info_array[$i]['nameID'] == $name_array[$j]){
       $info_array[$i]['nameID'] = $j;
     }   
   }         
}
```

Comment: I assume you're still editing your question?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same with the name colunm, but, if you have 500 names? Do you like to generate 500 if conditions? I not.

Comment: =] ha  yea, there are definitely more than 3 names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to expand your existing query to support the `NameID` column:

```
SELECT 
  name, type, spending, 
    CASE type 
       WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'Cash' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'Cheque' THEN 3 
    END AS TypeID, 
    CASE name 
       WHEN 'John' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'Brian' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'Frank' THEN 3 
    END AS NameID
FROM spendtable
```

As a design limitation, people stored in your database are only allowed to be named John, Brian, or Frank :)

Getting serious, assuming there are an unknown possible number of names I'm not sure you can (or would want to) do that kind of processing in the query. Instead, consider maintaining a separate `Name` table for keeping track of unique names:

```
NameID   Name
1        John
2        Brian
3        Frank
```

Your query could then join on this table:

```
SELECT 
  s.name, s.type, s.spending, 
    CASE s.type 
       WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'Cash' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'Cheque' THEN 3 
    END AS TypeID, 
    n.nameid
FROM spendtable s
JOIN Name n on n.name = s.name
```

Of course this would mean you needed to keep the `Name` table up to date, making sure to insert rows for new names.

Comment: Hi thanks Paul, yea i thought i would have to do something like that.  The alternative method i used was to make 2 queries, one for the info above and another to select distinct names. Then add the index of the name from the second table as the nameID for the first table.